# how to include a certificate in my webbrowser app

Tags: vb.net, ssl, https, certificate, webbrowser-control

I have made an app that will login automatically in the websites I use daily.
1 of them uses a security certificate which I have installed, when I browse it with IE I can accept the certificate and login, same with chrome, but when I browse with my app it will only show me

> Navigation to the webpage was canceled
>
> What you can try:
>     Refresh the page.

I'm thinking I have to somehow include that certificate on my app but I'm stuck, I've been googling about it but I can't find a straight answer.

I've read that the webbrowser control doesn't support HTTPS which the website I need to login is, if so is there any other way I can access the website within my app, maybe a different webbrowser control?

I'm using VB.net by the way.
some extra info:

I don't own the website so I cannot make any changes there.

I do have valid and legal access to the website using the certificate they issued for me.

Comment: On the other hand I just saw 2 of the other websites I have on my webbrowser app also are HTTPS and they work just fine, they don't require a certificate tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was I had browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
Somehow the browser control was taking the "Accept certificate" messagebox as script error.